# Date filter YESTERDAY excluding weekend

Tags: reporting

I have a problem using a dynamic filter on dates.
My report shows closed tasks from the previous day of the report launch using the dynamic date "Yesterday".
It works well except when you run the report on Monday. For SF, yesterday of Monday is Sunday (that is true) but I want a formula to say to SF that is today is Monday, yesterday is Friday...

Something like (IF dayofweek=monday then date filter=friday)

I could make the formula but I don't know how to call it from the filter window.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please share screenshot of your filter criteria

Answer (score 1):

The [YESTERDAY](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.filter_dates_relative.htm&type=5) relative filter is out of the box - so you have no option to change how that behaves.

You'll have to create your own custom formula field that returns a date on the object and then use that within the filter of the report.

1. Create formula field that returns a date (ex. `Business Days - Yesterday`)
2. Can utilize [WEEKDAY()](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5) which returns `2` for `Monday` and `1` for `Sunday` which are the only two scenarios you need to change

```
IF(
    WEEKDAY(TODAY()) = 1,
    TODAY() - 2,

    IF(
        WEEKDAY(TODAY()) = 2,
        TODAY() - 3,
        TODAY() - 1
    )
)
```

All the above formula is doing is the following

- TODAY() gives you the current date
- If the current date today is Sunday, subtract 2 days from the current
  date (get Friday's date).
- if the current date today is Monday, subtract 3 days from the current date (get Friday's date).

This is based on the following [IF syntax](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5).

```
IF(
    logical_test, 
    value_if_true, 
    value_if_false
)
```

3. Once you have the field, use it within your filter to compare against whatever field you're looking at (ex. filtering on CreatedDate being equal or greater than the last business day).

[image]

If this isn't a common use case (only for one specific report), you can do the same with just a [row-level formula](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_formulas_row_level_add.htm&type=0) that combines all of the above in one field per row in the report.

Comment: N.B. usual caveats that if this is the only field being filtered, then the query will be non-selective